# Autofill date pattern with Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to use Excel to fill a range of dates, the first and 15th of each month to be precise.

My spreadsheet currently looks like so:

[image: Current Spreadsheet]

When I drag down, it looks like so:

[image: New Spreadsheet]

Instead of continuing the pattern, it just repeats what's there. I have tried each of the following AutoFill options to no avail:

- Copy Cells
- Fill Series
- Fill Formatting Only
- Fill Without Formatting
- Fill Days
- Fill Weekdays
- Fill Months
- Fill Years

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to write a Excel Macro to accomplish this:

[image: dates]

```
Sub AddEntry()
    yr = "2012"
    x = ActiveCell.Row
    y = ActiveCell.Column
    For mon = 6 To 12
            Cells(x, y) = "01/" + CStr(mon) + "/" + yr
            Cells(x + 1, y) = "15/" + CStr(mon) + "/" + yr
            x = x + 2
            Cells(x, y).Select
    Next mon
End Sub
```

I actually used this to see to correct formatting, note the single quote.  But this changes the entry from a date to a string.

```
Cells(x, y) = "'01/" + CStr(mon) + "/" + yr
Cells(x + 1, y) = "'15/" + CStr(mon) + "/" + yr
```

Comment: Don't understand the downvote, this worked well, thanks!

Comment: @JMK: glad this worked for you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to use some simple functions.

1. First, add the first two dates 01/06/2012, 15/06/2012
2. On the third cell add this formula: `=DATE(YEAR($A1),MONTH($A1) + 1, DAY($A1))`
3. Drag down the third cell.

That's about it.

Comment: +1 ...looks like JMK has Excel 2010 so EDATE is built-in and you could shorten that formula with =EDATE(A1,1)